# what is the standard for password hash string encoding?

Tags: go, storage, glibc, portability, password-hash

I'm asking about the format used after the password is hashed and preparing it for storage. The dollar sign `$` annotation is something that seems to be widespread. Is that described in a standard somewhere (including the identifiers for algorithms)?

For example, when using Go with `golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt`, it gives such an encoded string ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/neMLaVNFLMO)):

```
func main() {
    h, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte("foo"), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", h)
    // Output: $2a$10$g1d5KuvDIrRoUyWL2BQs7uLOWCzlM.zqbRm8o364u20p20YNmJ.Ve
}
```

However, other hashing packages like `scrypt` ([example](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/scrypt#example-package)) and `argon2` return just the resulting hash. Using the `argon2` shell command, there is an encoded string returned:

```
echo "foo" | argon2 saltsalt
Type:           Argon2i
Iterations:     3
Memory:         4096 KiB
Parallelism:    1
Hash:           d9e4f94546b9e5b0cfb2dbf9dad81d41371845d8b6a8c25ce7caf23e13f1ef72
Encoded:        $argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$c2FsdHNhbHQ$2eT5RUa55bDPstv52tgdQTcYRdi2qMJc58ryPhPx73I
0.005 seconds
Verification ok
```

I found a Go / `argon2` specific [blog post](https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/how-to-hash-and-verify-passwords-with-argon2-in-go#storingpasswords) explaining this encoding, so far so good

## Variations I found

My trouble lies with the definition of the dollar separated string, the portability and variations I found.

### glibc

The [`man 3 crypt` page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) gives some pointers. There is a table of identifiers:

```
              ID   Method
              ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
              1    MD5
              2a   Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some Linux
                   distributions)
              5    SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
              6    SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
```

But this doesn't cover newer types, like `argon2i` or `scrypt`.

Then there are the example strings:

```
$id$salt$encrypted
$id$rounds=yyy$salt$encrypted
```

The latter being only supported after Glibc 2.7.

### bcrypt

While `bcrypt` uses the `2a` (blowfish) identifier from Glibc, its encoding seems to be slightly different as seen from the above example:

```
$2a$10$g1d5KuvDIrRoUyWL2BQs7uLOWCzlM.zqbRm8o364u20p20YNmJ.Ve
$id$cost$<dot seperated line of what exactly?>
```

### argon2

Argon2 uses 5 fields and a full name identifier like `argon2`

```
$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$c2FsdHNhbHQ$2eT5RUa55bDPstv52tgdQTcYRdi2qMJc58ryPhPx73I
$id$version$parameters$salt$encrypted
```

## why?

I want to write a package that hashes and verifies passwords in an algorithm agnostic way. Allowing the consumers to change parameters and algorithms without refactoring their code. Therefore during verification the package should be able to assert the algorithm used when storing the password. If stored version of parameters or algorithm is different than the one currently in use, the password is re-hashed and a new encoded string is returned.

As a bonus, I would like the package to have the ability to re-hash "legacy" passwords which might have been stored by older (not go) applications. For instance, `md5`. In order to do all this I would like to have a deeper understanding of the storage format itself.

Comment: The _standard_ hash string encoding is (trying to be) unbreakable ...  

Comment: There is no single standard for the storage format. If you want to write your own tool I recommend that you start with looking what formats widely established tools support first  - like  [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the standard for password hash string encoding?

There is none.

Hey, that was an easy answer! *Clicks "Post Your Answer"*.

Okay, while the above statement is unfortunately true, thankfully, there are some people who have already gone through the trouble of collecting a lot of information about all of the variations in use.

In particular, the authors of the [Passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/) library for Python (which does essentially the same thing you want to do) have written up a page about what they call the [*Modular Crypt Format*](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html) which they call "a standard that isn’t". Here are some choice quotes from that page [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> However, there’s ***no official specification document*** describing this format. ***Nor is there a central registry of identifiers***, or actual rules. The modular crypt format is more of an ad-hoc idea rather than a true standard.

[[Modular Crypt Format – Overview](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#overview)]

> Unfortunately, there is ***no specification document*** for this format. Instead, it exists in *de facto* form only

> When MCF was first introduced, most schemes choose a single digit as their identifier (e.g. `$1$` for **md5_crypt**). Because of this, some older systems ***only look at the first character*** when attempting to distinguish hashes.

> Most modular crypt format hashes follow this convention, though some (like **bcrypt**) ***omit the `$` separator*** between the configuration and the digest.

> [T]here is no set standard about whether configuration strings ***should or should not include a trailing `$` at the end***

[[Modular Crypt Format – Requirements](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#requirements)]

Please note that the Modular Crypt Format is *not* a specification or a standard. It is a *description* of the various different formats that are used in the wild. There *is* an attempt at a specification by the organizers of the [Password Hashing Competition (PHC)](https://password-hashing.net/#phc), called the [*PHC String Format*](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md). However, the PHC is no formal standards organization with any kind of authority. It is just a loose group of cryptographers. While they *recommend* that every new password hashing function should use the PHC String Format, they can only *mandate* it for password hashing functions that are submitted to the Password Hashing Competition.

And either way, the PHC String Format only applies to new password hashing functions, not to existing ones.

While I *strongly suggest* that you should use the PHC String Format for any output you generate, you will still have to deal with inputs in all sorts of different formats, [including some gems like these](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#cta):

> **cta_pbkdf2_sha1** and **dlitz_pbkdf2_sha1** both use the same identifier. While there are other internal differences, the two can be quickly distinguished by the fact that cta hashes always end in `=`, while dlitz hashes contain no `=` at all.